# How to solve set problems using algebra?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm a beginner math student and I'm studying sets. I've studied some things relating sets and am now trying to solve my first exercises. The first of which have to do with understanding whether certain propositions are true (also using some tricky iff or "only if" logic). For example here's a problem where I have to choose which of these propositions is *true*:

1. A    ∩ (B    ∪ C)    =   (A  ∩ B)    ∪ C     if and only if  C   ⊆ A
2. A    ∩ (B    ∪ C)    =   (A  ∩ B)    ∪ C     only if C   ⊆ A
3. A    ∩ (B    ∪ C)    =   (A  ∩ B)    ∪ C     if and only if  C   =   A
4. A    ∩ (B    ∪ C)    =   (A  ∩ B)    ∪ C     only if C   =   A

What I'm lacking is the procedure on how to solve these. Currently, what I do, is I start by assigning some random values to each set and I see whether the proposition holds, if it doesn't I know it's false. However, this can be quite a cumbersome process that takes some time so I was wondering whether there was a more algebraic way of solving these set problems instead of trial/error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you'll want to recap that
$$A \text{ if and only if } B$$
Means $A\implies B$ and $A \impliedby B$, so you must show two things there for a proof.
Secondly
$$A \text{ only if } B$$
Means $A\implies B$.

---

Now to show such a thing, start with the assumption (what is at the beginning of the arrow) and try to deduce the implication (what is at the end of the arrow).
Note that your specific case allows you to save some work because 2. and 4. are "weaker" versions of 1. and 3..

I'll give you a start:

> Let $C\subseteq A$. We try to deduce $A\cap (B\cup C) = (A\cap B)\cup C$ - this is the "$\impliedby$"-direction.
>   Using de Morgans rules we know
>   $$A \cap (B\cup C) = (A\cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$$
>   now since $C\subseteq A$, $A\cap C = C$ so
>   $$\ldots = (A\cap B) \cup C$$
>   as was to show.

You can now check in a similar way if $A\cap (B\cup C) = (A\cap B) \cup C \implies C \subseteq A$ et cetera. Note that in this direction, you can use that said equality is valid *for all* $B$. So a good idea would be to pick a special $B$ (**Hint**: $B=\emptyset$) to yield a special equality in terms of only $A$ and $C$.

Also note that we already proved $C\subseteq A \implies \text{equation}$. Now since $C=A \implies C\subseteq A$, you don't need to check
$$C=A\implies A\cap (B\cup C) = (A\cap B)\cup C$$
separately.

Comment: Interesting so I can apply DeMorgan's Law even for sets? I thought that was only meant for boolean algebra. Also isn't DeMorgan only for NOT's stuff (complement), such as (A + B)' = A' and B' (where ' means complement or NOT)?

Comment: @LucaMatteis There is a set-theoretic analogous. The common name seems to be [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property).

Comment: So I can apply all boolean algebra to sets?

Comment: @LucaMatteis As said, there are **analogies**. Most boolean formulas have a corresponding set theoretic formula. For example $\neg \neg A = A$ corresponds to $(A^C)^C = A$ where $A^C$ is the complement of $A$ in the current universe.

Comment: Thanks. Using some of my knowledge with boolean algebra is helping enormously. Just one question. I'm not clear how to go the other way with A∩(B∪C)=(A∩B)∪C⟹C⊆A - I have to assume the stuff on the left be true and see whether C⊆A holds, right? But I can't seem to break down the right part into any smaller pieces (as you did with the one on the left using the distributive property).

Comment: @LucaMatteis Take the tip from my answer. What if $B$ takes special values like $B = \emptyset$?

Comment: Ah then I'm left with A ∩ C = C. Which is my assumption. So it holds. Interesting thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

You could write them as:
$A\cup B = \left\{x:\:x \in A \vee x \in B\right\}$ 
and
$A\cap B = \left\{x:\: \in A \wedge x \in B\right\}$

And see where that gets you?

Method 2: Visual

The other way of doing this is by drawing Venn Diagrams. This is not my preferred method, but generally you'd draw a box and within that box, some circles. You can then check for the overlaps (etc) of sets. For instance, suppose you have two circles that overlap, but not fully. $A\cup B$ would be both circles and their overlap, but $A\cap B$ would only be the overlap.

You'd then make three circles (A,B,C). You can then draw $A \cup B$ and the intersect of that with C, and do the same (in a separate image?) for the other, and see if they're the same.

I believe this visual method is the one most of my fellow students use.

Comment: This method is restricted to three sets in general position, unless you have 3D-paper to draw a tetrahedron-shape with spheres at the vertices.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when the exercise says, decide which of the following propositions is true, I generally start by thinking about a counter example. Of course the more you practice, the more counter examples you will have in mind, and it will be easier (in the case that it is false) to find the precise one.

If you've been thinking for a while, or fore some reason, you think the statement is true, maybe you do a drawing in this case, and it works and you are almost sure the proposition is valid, you proceed to the proof.

1)If you have a proposition of the type

$p$ if and only if $q$

To show that this statement is true, you have to show that if $p$ is true, then $q$ is true, and that if $q$ is true then $p$ is true.

For example in your first example, you will first have to suppose that

$A\cap(B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup C)$ and you have to try to show that $C\subset A$.

To show the converse you should suppose that $C\subset A$ and try to prove that $A\cap(B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup C)$.

That would complete an if and only if demonstration.

2)If you have

$p$ only if $q$ you have to show that if $p$ is true, then $q$ is true. In this case, in example 2) you should suppose that $A\cap(B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup C)$ and try to prove that $C\subset A$.

Comment: The "only if" part is wrong. $p$ only if $q$ translates to $p\implies q$. (Think $p$ can only be true if $q$ is also true)

Comment: I mixed up the letters! Thanks